# IndexError when dropping rows in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
for (i1, row1), (i2, row2) in pairwise(df.iterrows()):
    if row1['months_to_maturity'] == row2['months_to_maturity'] and
            row1['coupon'] == row2['coupon']:
        df = df.drop(df.index[[i1]])
```

What I am trying to do is to get rid of rows if the following condition is satisfied

```
row1['months_to_maturity'] == row2['months_to_maturity'] and
    row1['coupon'] == row2['coupon']
```

The `pairwise(df.iterrows())` method gives the current row and the next row of the `dataframe`.

Unfortunately, when I execute the code above I get this error

> IndexError: index 12 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 12

I did `print(len(df.index))` at the beginning of this section and got `12` printed, so I am slightly confused why `IndexError` raises.

Comment: why don't use drop_duplicates based on the two columns? `df.drop_duplicates(('months_to_maturity','coupon'),inplace=True)`

Comment: Must the duplicate rows appear contiguously, or do you want to drop duplicates wherever they appear?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thank You. I just assumed I wouldn't be able to use it for particular columns.

Comment: @HappyLeapSecond The duplicate rows appear contiguously.

Comment: @user131983, no prob, the default is for all but you can pass a *subset : column label or sequence of labels,* http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: @user131983, you probably alter the dataframe and by doing so its size is changed. Try to think of a different way to access the rows instead of the using their `index`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are iterating over rows, matching a condition and then drop rows based on the condition that is met. I don't think this is the optimum way of doing what you are trying to do.

I am going to recommend that do things completely differently. Try this, given dataframe df,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,5]})
df['b'] = df.a
print (df)
   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3
3  4  4
4  4  4
5  4  4
6  5  5
7  5  5
8  5  5
```

To get to the next row, I could do,

```
df_next = df.shift()
print (df_next)
    a   b
0 NaN NaN
1   1   1
2   2   2
3   3   3
4   4   4
5   4   4
6   4   4
7   5   5
8   5   5
```

To find the matching rows and drop them , I could do,

```
df2 = df.drop(df.index[(df.b==df_nxt.b) & (df.a==df_nxt.a)])
   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3
3  4  4
6  5  5
```

Effectively, this boils down to two lines of code,

```
df_next = df.shift()
df2 = df.drop(df.index[(df.b==df_nxt.b) & (df.a==df_nxt.a)])
```

This is the magic of pandas